# React Redux doesn't return expected state

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose, redux

I have a like function on the backend (Node, MongoDB) that returns the given post with updated `likes` counter. This works, tested it with Postman. This is just an object with a bunch of properties like `likes`, `_id.`, `by`, `createdAt` and so on...

```
let p = await Post.findById(req.params.id).populate("by");
return res.json(p);
```

Then I have a `like` action in React:

```
export const like = (id) => (dispatch) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (token) {
        axios
            .put(`http://localhost:5000/likePost/${id.id}`, id, {
                headers: { "X-Auth-Token": token },
            })
            .then((res) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: LIKE,
                    payload: res.data,
                });
            });
    }
};
```

And I have a `LIKE` reducer:

```
case LIKE:
   return {
      ...state,
      posts: state.posts.map((p) => {
         return { ...p };
   }),
};
```

The `LIKE` reducer triggers when I click on the button and on the backend I can see the update but on the client side it doesn't update. I use `redux-logger` and the `posts` state is not updated.

What did I do wrong? I thought that spreading all the posts (`...p`) will update it, since it is updated on the backend.

Comment: You are using the old data of posts from the state. You have to use the `action.payload` field to update the posts key in your state.

Comment: You dispatch your type `LIKE`, but what do with the `payload`? You have to use `payload` to get your new posts (that are returned from your server)

Comment: Your final state will be `{...state, posts: {...state.posts, ...action.payload}`. It will merge existing posts with your new posts `action.payload` and update the `posts` state.

Comment: the `action.payload` is the `res.data` that is coming from the server. that is only one object, an updated `post` with the updated `likes`. while `posts` is an array in my state. so do I need to return all the posts from the server?

Comment: `{...state, posts: {...state.posts, ...action.payload}` almost works, I get an error because in the state now the object that is returned is inside the `posts` array which shouldn't be. the old object (in posts) should be replaced with the new object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works:

```
          case LIKE:
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: state.posts.map((p) => {
                    if (p._id === action.payload._id) {
                        p.likes = action.payload.likes;
                    }
                    return p;
                }),
            };
```